# Count every product sold

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count every product sold from 2 tables in my database

Heres the code :

```
SELECT a.nama_barang as Produk, 
       (SELECT COUNT(merek) 
          FROM transaksi 
          WHERE merek LIKE '%a.nama_barang%') AS Quantity 
FROM tb_barang a
```

the problem in the query above returns 0:

[image]

Transaction Table :

[image]

Comment: Hi sena. This is weird: merek LIKE '%a.nama_barang%'. Data in column transaksi  equal a.nama_barang? a is an alias. You gave us want you tried, can you tell us what you want and give us in text some sample data please. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should JOIN the tables and use GROUP BY, rather than making nested SELECT query for a column. Other than that, the `CONCAT` function can build a string to use for LIKE:

```
SELECT a.nama_barang as Produk, COUNT(*) FROM tb_barang a
JOIN transaksi b ON b.merek LIKE CONCAT('%', a.nama_barang, '%')
GROUP BY a.nama_barang
```

The above should be close, you can make whichever extra changes you would like.